# Image did not come out when run the program

Tags: c#

i already create a picturebox and have image inside it. But when i run the program, the image didn't show anything, just sign "x" (didn't load) when i run the program.

Where do i did wrong?

Here is the code:

```
private void Images(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
            pb1.ImageLocation = "SamuderaJayaMotor.png";
            pb1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb1.Size = new Size(200, 200);
            this.Controls.Add(pb1);
        }
```

Here is the screenshot when i run the program:

[image]

Comment: Where is your image located on the machine? What you have here will attempt to load it from the working directory of the executable.

Comment: Maybe the image location is the problem?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: on the machine, it is located at inside of the folder of this form. Then, what should i do sir? do i need to include the full path?

Edit: Thanks sir, it is correct, i have to include full path

Comment: give image location properly

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the image is in the same directory as the executable. That is, whilst you are creating your application, it will live in the `/bin/Debug` folder. If you are running in Release mode, it will be in the `/bin/Release` folder.

By supplying just a file name, your application is attempting to load the image from the current working directory. If you run your application in `C:\MyApp`.. then your image must also be inside `C:\MyApp`. If you are running it from `D:\Projects\MyApp`, then your image must also be in `D:\Projects\MyApp`.

What you can do.. is set your image to always copy to where your executable is. Right click on the image in the Solution Explorer and go to Properties. Then set the following property to "Copy always":

[image: Copy always]

This will make sure the image is placed into the directory that your application is built in.